# how to count the nonzero mismatches between two tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have two tensors in tensorflow, A, B (of the same shape).  Suppose these are both sparse.  I need to know a count of the instances where one of these tensors has a nonzero value at a given index, while the other tensor has a zero value.  So, I am looking for a number of locations (i,j pairs) where one matrix has a nonzero value there and the other matrix has a zero value there.  How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I would do as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tensor1 = tf.constant([[0, 1], [0, 2]])
tensor2 = tf.constant([[1, 0], [0, 2]])
a = tf.math.equal(tensor1, tf.zeros_like(tensor1))
b = tf.math.equal(tensor2, tf.zeros_like(tensor2))
c = tf.math.equal(a, b)
c = tf.cast(c, tf.int32)
c = tf.math.reduce_sum(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it. It sums the `True` cases according to these conditions, element-wise:

1. `a` and `b` have non-equal values
2. `a` is not zero
3. `b` is not zero

```
tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
        tf.logical_and(
            tf.not_equal(tf.sparse.to_dense(a), tf.sparse.to_dense(b)),
            tf.cast(tf.sparse.to_dense(a), tf.bool),
            tf.cast(tf.sparse.to_dense(b), tf.bool)),
        tf.int32))
```

Based on these two sparse tensors:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 1]])>
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1]])>
```

Complete example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]],
                    values=[1, 2, 1, 2, 1], dense_shape=[3, 3])
b = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]],
                    values=[2, 2, 2, 2, 1], dense_shape=[3, 3])

tf.sparse.to_dense(a)
tf.sparse.to_dense(b)

tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(
        tf.logical_and(
            tf.not_equal(tf.sparse.to_dense(a), tf.sparse.to_dense(b)),
            tf.cast(tf.sparse.to_dense(a), tf.bool),
            tf.cast(tf.sparse.to_dense(b), tf.bool)),
        tf.int32))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
    [[0,1], [1,1]], [1,2], [2,2]
)
b = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(
    [[0,0], [0,1],[1,0]], [1,2,1], [2,2]
)

res = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.cast(tf.math.logical_xor(
        tf.math.not_equal(tf.sparse.to_dense(a), 0), 
        tf.math.not_equal(tf.sparse.to_dense(b), 0)
    ), 'int32')
)
```

Comment: @NicolasGervais, I simply create two boolean arrays to indicate where a or b got non-zero values. If I do xor on those two boolean arrays, I get True at each position where one array has a non-zero element. (For xor - (0,0 -> 0) / (0,1 -> 1) / (1,0 -> 1) / (1,1 -> 0))